# How to echo correctly from json_decode in php

Tags: json, echo

so i am trying to echo array data from json_decode, i have tried several ways, but nothing seems to work, how to do this correctly?

Heres my code:

```
<?php
$jsonstring = file_get_contents('example.com/json'); //get the string
$decoded = json_decode($jsonstring, true);   //decode the string
echo $decoded[roadDamage][0][place]; //echo array content
?>
```

Echo part simply doesnt work, it echos nothing...

My decoded array looks like this, i am intrested in roadDamage array, and values of place,time

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($decoded)
```

will print all your array. If nothing is printed then you misspelled indexes. BTW better put indexes of associative arrays in `''`

Answer (score 0):

Your indexes need to be in quotes. Otherwise PHP looks for a constant with that name, rather than interpreting it as a string.

Change:
echo $decoded[roadDamage][0][place];

To:
echo $decoded['roadDamage'][0]['place'];

Comment: Thanks that pointed me to right way, and i got it working like this echo $ll['roadDamage']['data'][0]['place'];